# Ubuntu on ssd and windows

Tags: boot, ssd

I have recently bought a laptop with 32gb ssd and 750 gb hdd.
Due to my job I need both windows and linux (I use more linux than windows).
I want to install first windows 7 on the hdd and later ubuntu on the ssd (/home on the hdd)
Do you think it is a good idea?

Comment: please see a possible answer http://superuser.com/questions/316570/should-i-install-my-operating-system-on-my-ssd-or-hdd

Answer (score 0):

I have also bought a laptop some months ago with Windows 7 pre-installed on HDD, and I then installed Ubuntu on SSD, and my experience (as well as my research on the internet) shows that it was **a good decision in deed** :-)

1. Ubuntu boots and works faster (also including the fact that I
   reduce the Grub timeout to 0 (zero) so that the computer normally
   boots direct to Ubuntu desktop).
2. When I need to use Windows at all (I don't remember using it for
   months, except just checking if it works this way ;-) I simply use
   F12 to go into the Boot Menu and choose HDD to boot.